# How to restrict google forms submission based on two ID using GAS on Google Form or Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm working on a query Google Form which collects participants' votes to a certain question. I want to restrict participants based on the ID number. I was thinking of three approaches:

1. Prevent form submission if the entered ID is not on the given list. (I prefer this approach but couldn't find any useful code for it so far)
2. Delete rows in the linked responses spreadsheet after form submission using *GAS on Google Form* through onFormSubmit trigger. Here is my code which is not working:

   ```
   function onFormSubmit(e) {
    // Grab the session data again so that we can match it to the user's choices.
   var response = [];
   var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1rT9tKAi6ZSvZzBaXNSPMJAt4RKnW- 
    9lqiE9zvZV').getDataRange().getValues();

   for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
     var indiv = values[I];
     var Fname = indiv[0];
     var Lname = indiv[1];
     var ID1 = indiv[2];
     var ID2 = indiv[3];

     // For every selection in the response, find the matching ID1 and title
     // in the spreadsheet and add the session data to the response array.
     if (e.namedValues[ID1] == ID1) {
       response.push(indiv);
     } else {
     Browser.msgBox('Your ID number does not matches the list');
     }
   }
   ```
3. Delete rows in the linked responses spreadsheet after form submission using *GAS on Google Sheets* through onChange trigger. Here is my best effort:

   ```
   function onChange(e) {  
    var refvalues = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('members_sheet').getDataRange().getValues();
    var  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    var  values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var indiv = values[values.length];
    var ID1 = indiv[2];
    var flag = 0;
     for (var i = 1; i < refvalues.length; i++) {
         var refindiv = refvalues[i];
         var refID1 = refindiv[2];
       if (ID1 == refID1) {
         flag = 1;
       }
    } 

    if (flag == 0) {
      sheet.deleteRow(values.length); 
    }
    };
   ```

I'm totally new in Javascript coding so any help would be appreciated.

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

Thanks to the ziganotschka answer I update my code to this:

```
function makeMultiForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Nazar Sanji')
                .setConfirmationMessage('Thank you! Your Vote have been 
    recorded');
  form.setTitle("Query");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1rT9tKAi6ZSvZzBaXNSPMJAt4RKnW- 
   9lqiE9zvZV5JJk');
  var ID1List = 
    ss.getSheetByName('members_sheet').getRange('C2:C4').getValues();//Ex [123 ; 555]
  var ID2List = 
    ss.getSheetByName('members_sheet').getRange('D2:D4').getValues();//Ex [aa ; bb]

  // Ex passwords: asd, 123, asd123
  const condition1 = ID1List.map(element => `${element}`).join('|')

  var IDarray =[];
  //Add items to IDarray Ex [123aa ; 555bb]
    for(var i=0; i<ID1List.length; i++){
        IDarray[i] = [ID1List[i][0]+ID2List[i][0]];
    }
  const condition2 = IDarray.map(element => `${element}`).join('|')

  // Start by laying out the bare-bones structure.  This defines the different
  // sections, and the bare widgets in each section.
  // Note that you can't add any flow-routing details at this point, because
  // the destinations most likely haven't been defined yet

  var itemFName = form.addTextItem().setTitle('First Name').setRequired(true);
  var itemLName = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Last Name').setRequired(true);
  var itemID1   = form.addTextItem().setTitle('First ID').setRequired(true);

  // Create valid ation for this question matching the ID1(ID Melli) that we got from the sheet
  var ID1Validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
.setHelpText('Enter a Valid First ID')
.requireTextMatchesPattern(condition1)
.build();
  itemID1.setValidation(ID1Validation);

  //var sectID2 = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Second ID");
  var itemID2 = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Second ID').setRequired(true);

  // Create valid ation for this question matching the ID2(ID Shenasnameh) that we got from the sheet
  var ID2Validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
.setHelpText('Second ID does not match the First ID')
.requireTextMatchesPattern(condition2)
.build();
  itemID2.setValidation(ID2Validation);


  var sectVote = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Final Vote");
  var VoteOptions = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Which Competition");
  VoteOptions.setChoices([
  VoteOptions.createChoice("Option 1"),
  VoteOptions.createChoice("Option 2")]);

}
```

The recent issue is on ID2validation. Since *condition2* is the concatenation of two ID numbers, the participant has to enter his/her merged ID's (passwords) in the last text item in the Google Form which is not correct. (Ex. '123aa')

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

### Prevent form submission if the entered ID is not on the given list

- The easiest way would be to incorporate text validation, you do not even need to code for it
- Just chose when building / editing the `ID1` question `Regular expression`, `matches` and specify all IDs that shall be allowed to submit the form using `|` as separator

[image]

**Further information**

> - If you feel motivated to incorporated the text validation programmatically, have a look
>     [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder#)
>     and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60530768/11599789)
> - If you prefer to work on your already existing code to delete rows - it does not matter either you attach the script to the form or the
>     spreadsheet, in both cases you can and should use the trigger
>     `onFormSubmit` (not `onChange`!)
> - Deleting rows from the form submission sheet will not work - they come back at the next form submission
> - Copying `onFormSubmit` the rows with the right ID to a secondary sheet can work, but it more complicated than using text validation

Comment: Dear ziganotschka, Thanks for sharing the solution. The issue answer on your second link was almost the same as my question. In my case, the participant should provide two password (ID number) to verify as an eligible individual to continue the form. The recent issue is to concatenate the second ID number with the first one in the data validation field. please refer to my answer to the question.

Comment: If you want a validation to take place before the form is submitted, unfortunately it is not possible to check either ID2 corresponds to the chosen ID1 dynamically. You would need to ask the user to enter a combination of his ID1 and ID2 concatenated in the same field. Then you can compare it against the concatenated values in your spreadsheet. Small note: for next time, in agreement with Stackoverflow community guidelines, please modify your old question rather than providing the update as an answer (or post a new question if it is different enough from the original one).

Comment: Thanks for reminding guideline and your solution. Actually it's my first time posting in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer keeping all of the ids on a spreadsheet try this in the beginning of your code.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('your id');
  const idsh=ss.getSheetByName('id sheet');
  const idrg=ss.getRange(2,1,idsh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  const idA=idrg.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  if (idA.indexOf(e.namedValues['ID1'])==-1) {
    Browser.msgBox('Your ID number does not match the list');
    return;
  }
  //rest of your code here

}
```

Comment: Dear Cooper, Thanks for your recommendation. I have got this error after trying: "The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange"

Comment: What line is it on?  I'm guessing you have other onEdits in your code because I don't see a line with that problem in my code.

Comment: This is the only possibility `ss.getRange(2,1,idsh.getLastRow()-1,1);` and that one looks okay.

Comment: The reason for getting this error is `const idrg=ss.getRange(2,1,idsh.getLastRow()-1,1);` - modify it to `const idrg=idsh.getRange(2,1,idsh.getLastRow()-1,1);`

Comment: The error is gone but I didn't get msgbox on the wrong ID and the vote is submitted in google sheet as well.

Comment: Sorry I missed that