# How secure is field validation in Google Forms?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

Some people are using this data validation pattern to protect forms:

1. [A youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HIf8qCSwfA&vl=en) from Google for Education uses this pattern.
2. [A similar scenario to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324520/) with a similarly proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325496/1985071).

Since Google for Education showcases this pattern, I want to believe it is reasonably secure. But I also understand the above solution is client-side validation, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18649165/1985071).

Logically, doesn't this imply the validation values and logic can be exposed by scraping/viewing the source? How safe is it to store passwords and unique IDs as a regex in these validation fields?

For context, I'm hoping to use Google Forms + GAS for verified, unique form submissions from a set of non-google account emails while reducing quota usage from spam/misuse.

Answer (score 1):

It's not secure. All client side validations are insecure by design. Pattern validation passwords are visible in the source code. Having said that, a single password for multiple users is also insecure. All it takes is one user compromise to invalidate the whole thing.

If you need a fully secure solution, create your own form with HtmlService with oauth authorization and Google identity.