# Google Form response validation from a value of spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am designing a google form where the approvers need to put a password to authenticate themselves as approver. The password is randomly generated by a google speadsheet and the  password is shared with the approvers before approving.

Now my query is, when the approver will put the password in the google form, how the form will validate the password to check whether this is the same password distributed to approvers.

Pls let me know incase there is any way.

Comment: Hi there! Is this related to programming and is there some code you are using to try to validate the passwords? If so, please edit your answer to include the code, and add the corresponding language tag. Stack Overflow is for a specific programming problem. If you are looking for help related to the use of Google Forms, then this is not the place to ask.

Comment: Do you have only one general password or will every user have his own?

Comment: Embed the form in a web page and put a basic password there.

Comment: Hi ziganotschka, The password would be new for every approver as it would be randomly generated by the RAND function and will be shared with the approvers with a notification. The password will be stored in a google spreadsheet. I need help to understand how the google form will validate the password when the approver will put the same.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325496/11599789). You can either populate the data validation with data from the spreadsheet, or - if you no only want to check that the password is valid, but also if the username-password combinaiton is correct - you will need to ask the user to type a combination of his user name and password as a response to a question.