# I'm trying to make my Google form viewable to everyone (outside work domain too) but only one user can submit the form via appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

```
function restrict() {
                var form = FormApp.openById('');
                var user = Session.getActiveUser()
                if (user.getEmail() == '123@gmail.com){
                    form.setAcceptingResponses(true)
             }
     }
```

This the app-script I'm using, I've set the trigger on form open as well. But it's not working.

Comment: The `Open` trigger for a Google Form [does not occur when a user opens a form to respond, but rather when an editor opens the form to modify it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#open_3).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict google forms submission based on two ID using GAS on Google Form or Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324520/how-to-restrict-google-forms-submission-based-on-two-id-using-gas-on-google-form)